# If matching true, remove the matching word and return the rest of word

Tags: java

I have method like the following. I have two array lists.

First array list contains: brand names.

Eg:Hermanos

Second array list contains: product names followed by the brand name.

Eg: Hermanos Baby Onion

I want to remove the brand name from the product array list and return the product name without the brand. Eg: Baby Onion

For that purpose I have created this following code. But I have the difficulty to do so. I have commented the place.

```
public void checkArrayListStatus(ArrayList getBrandName, ArrayList getProductName) {
        log.debug("The Size of Brand Name ArrayList : " + getBrandName.size());
        log.debug("The Size of Product Name ArrayList : " + getProductName.size());


        for (int i = 0; i < getBrandName.size(); i++) {
            String brandName = getBrandName.get(i).toString();
            String productName = getProductName.get(i).toString();
            if (productName.contains(brandName)) {
                System.out.println("Matched");
                //  if matching true, remove the matching word and return the rest of word
            } else {
                System.out.println("Didnot Match !!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could use String's `substring()` function for that.

Comment: @Beka the problem is though some of the product have the name like this. Eg: Hermanos Baby Onion. Some contains products like this. Eg: BBB Best Strawberry Jelly. The brand name of this is BBB Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (productName.contains(brandName)) {
      System.out.println("Matched");
      productName = productName.replace (brandName, "");
} else {
      System.out.println("Didnot Match !!");
}
```

Comment: `productName.replace (brandName, "");` is a NOP.

Comment: As @xehpuk mentioned, that line is a NOP. It doesn't do anything. So either you should remove it OR do `productName = productName.replace(brandName, "");`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` in java for this task.

Check this out.

```
productName.replace (brandName, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` for this purpose. Try the below mentioned line.

```
productName.replace (brandName, "");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
return productName.replace (brandName, "");
```

This will replace the brandname by an empty string, essentially removing it.

I also suggest changing the parameter type from

```
ArrayList
```

to

```
ArrayList <String>
```

. Then you can also leave the toString conversions out.

Comment: [Formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) is important.  Also what do you mean by `from "ArrayList" to "ArrayList/"`?

Comment: Can't get the smaller than token to work... Html :(. Do you know how to fig that?